# Options(session variable??) to get set checkbox value with MVC paging and sorting

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my html.beginform I have this checkbox that I want to persist. I'm not sure how to add it to the below ActionLink...or if it is even possible. I thought of using a session variable. If anyone has an example showing how to set a checkbox value in a session variable that would be awesome...or if there is a way to pass it in the ActionLink...that would be cool too.
cheers and thanks in advance

```
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(model=>model.wccrSelection.SendDemand)

      @Html.ActionLink("Order",
        "Display", new {Model.wccrSelection.WccrId,sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to add additional parameter for passing checkbox state to your action method as shown below:

Eg.:

```
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model=>model.wccrSelection.SendDemand, new {@class = "SendDemand"})
    @Html.ActionLink("Order",
            "Display", new {Model.wccrSelection.WccrId,sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm }, new { @class = "DisplayOrder" })

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function(){
          (".DisplayOrder").on.("click",function(){
          var href = $(this).attr("href");
          if ($(".SendDemand").is(':checked')) {
            href = href + "&CheckBoxState=true";
          } 
          else {
            href = href + "&CheckBoxState=false";
          }
          $(this).attr("href", href);
        });
       });
</script>
```

Comment: Kapil, how do I call this function from my html.Checkbox helper? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `<form>` instead of a link. This way the value of the checkbox will be automatically sent to the controller and you don't need to use any javascript:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Display", null, new { id = Model.wccrSelection.WccrId, sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm }))
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model=>model.wccrSelection.SendDemand)
    <button type="submit">Order</button>
}
```

Comment: Darin, thanks for this response. I ended up using the javascript solution, but I learned a lot by trying this response and it gave me a different way of thinking of how to solve issues. cheers